# In redux toolkit in ecommerce webite , When I add product to cart total price changes from 0 to null

Tags: reactjs, mern, tailwind-ui

In the redux toolkit on the eCommerce website, When  I add the product to the cart total price changes from 0 to null. I have been struggling with this problem.Instead of null it should show the total cart price by adding product prices

This is the Cart slice of the e-commerce website in redux-toolkit

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: {
    products: [],
    quantity: 0,
    total: 0,
  },
  reducers: {
    addProduct: (state, action) => {
      state.products.push(action.payload);
      state.quantity += 1;
      state.total += action.payload.price * action.payload.quantity;
    },
    removeProduct: (state, action) => {
        let index = state.products.indexOf(action.payload)
        state.quantity -= action.payload
        state.products.splice(index, 1)
    }
  },
});

export const { addProduct ,removeProduct} = cartSlice.actions;
export default cartSlice.reducer;
```

This is the Product page of an E-commerce website. Last function   `const addtocart=()=>{dispatch(addProduct({...product,quantity}))}` add product to cart.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import  {useDispatch, useSelector} from  "react-redux"
import { addProduct } from '../ReduxToolkit/features/cartSlice'

const ProductPage = () => {
const quantity = useSelector((state) => state.cart.quantity)

const dispatch=useDispatch()
const { id } = useParams("")
const [product, setProduct] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
const getData = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`/products/oneproduct/${id}`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
    const data = await res.json()

    if (res.status !== 200) {
      console.log("no data present")
    } else {
   
      setProduct(data)
    }
  }
  getData()
  }, [id])

const addtocart=()=>{dispatch(addProduct({...product,quantity}))}

return (
    <div>
      <section className="text-gray-600 body-font font-abc overflow-hidden">
        <div className="container px-5 py-16 mx-auto">
          <div className="lg:w-4/5 mx-auto flex align-middle justify-center flex-wrap">
            <img alt="ecommerce" className="lg:w-1/3 w-[230px]  object-contain lg:h-96 md:h-76   rounded" src={product.oneProduct?.img} />
            <div className="lg:w-1/2 w-full lg:pl-10 lg:py-6 mt-6 lg:mt-0">
              <h2 className="text-sm title-font font-semibold text-gray-500 my-2 tracking-widest">{product.oneProduct?.cat}</h2>
              <h1 className="text-gray-900 text-3xl my-4 title-font font-bold mb-1">{product.oneProduct?.title}</h1>

              <p className="leading-relaxed">{product.oneProduct?.desc}</p>
              <div className="flex mt-6 items-center pb-5 border-b-2 border-gray-100 mb-5">

                <div className="flex ml-6 items-center">


                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="flex">
                <span className="title-font font-medium text-2xl text-gray-900">$&nbsp;{product.oneProduct?.price}</span>
                <button className=" cart flex ml-4 text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0  py-2 px-4 focus:outline-none lg:w-32 hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded md:w-4  md:px-6 text-sm" onClick={addtocart}>Add to cart</button>
                <Link to="/cart">
                <button  className=" cart flex ml-4 text-white bg-indigo-500 border-0  py-2 px-4 focus:outline-none lg:w-32 hover:bg-indigo-600 rounded md:w-4  md:px-6 text-sm">Order page
                </button>
                </Link>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductPage
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

- Check your getting data from the fetch call
- Check your local state against your redux state
- See your call stack and Redux dev tools
- Hard code state values until you can get it to work
  -Keep in mind redux will send back 200 response on every fetch call even the ones that fail, use originalStatus instead of status for your response check

My first indication of why you are getting null starts with the optional chaining pointing right at `oneProduct` saying it does not exist and/or your price is null on this line

`{product.oneProduct?.price}` is it possible that oneProduct does not exist yet on first render? since it's reading the useState local values and not the  redux state?

Here's an example of how I would get the total price, and you could use this concept to get the singular price of a product as well
I would put this in cartSlice `export const selectCurrentTotal = (state) => state.total;`

Then in Product page import the selectCurrentTotal like this
`import { selectCurrentTotal } from '../features/cart/cartSlice';`
and use it like this `const total = useSelector(selectCurrentTotal);`
Now we can replace the `{product.oneProduct?.price}` with `total`

You should use the useSelector to grab the products out of the redux state just like you did with quantity. Try hard coding oneProduct and see if this is the issue. I would not store any state values needed in redux in local useState just my own preference.

I would suggest removing the useEffect, your cartService.js should be handling all the fetch calls (builder mutations) and then your reducers in cartSlice handling the actions and state updates. A fetch call should have trycatch to help keep it clean and error free.
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#asynchronous-logic-and-data-fetching

What does your call stack say? and does Redux Dev Tools show the price getting updated at all or any products added to your state?